# Страна()производитель

Tags: орфография

Столкнулся в одном тексте с термином "страна()производитель". Предложение было такое: "...в качестве страны производителя до сегодняшнего момента на этикетке обозначалось место, где произведена расфасовка товара".
Я писал раздельно, но, честно говоря, у меня возникли сомнения: может быть, тут нужно было ставить дефис и писать "страна-производитель"?
Как правильно?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Правильно: страна-производитель.

Это одиночное приложение, стоящее после определяемого слова, пишется через дефис.